# Newrelic rpm does not work with Rails 5 + Rocketpant

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, newrelic, rocketpants

I recently upgrade my Rails app from 4.2.5 to 5.0.2

Everything works fine except Newrelic RPM to track our API performance.

On Rails 4.2.5, we are using a folk of the gem 'rocket_pants-rpm' to make Newrelic track Rocketpants API endpoint correctly.

https://github.com/Sutto/rocket_pants-rpm/pull/3/files

But after upgrading to 5.0.2, this fork does not work anymore.

I am not very familiar with how the Newrelic agent works, any idea to make Newrelic work with Rails 5 + Rocketpants again?

Comment: Some additional info: I am using the latest newrelic-rpm gem version 4.0.0.332

Answer (score 0):

I fix the issue myself. It turns out the gem rocket_pants-rpm doesn't load Newrelic agent since it does NOT check Rails major version 5.

I have submitted a pull request

https://github.com/Sutto/rocket_pants-rpm/pull/4

Which solves this issue, now Newrelic shows my API endpoints under namespace Api::V1 again : )

[image]